# Labview: Access denied: Another process is using this target

Tags: labview

I have a Labview 2013 project that makes use of a NI RT controller. Upon the start of the main VI everything is deployed on the target system (the RT controller). Therefore an ethernet connection is used.

**Problem:**

When loosing the connection to the target RT controller, I'm unable to later redeploy my project. Labview reports unresolved conflicts:

> **Access denied: Another project is using this target.** You must disconnect the existing project from the target or restart the target before establishing a new connection. Note: The existing project may be running on a different host computer.

The same error message appears, when I try to re-connect to the target system from Project Explorer.

When right-clicking on the target in Labview Project Explorer the `Disconnect` context menu item is disabled. Thus it's not possible to disconnect the project from the target. Since restarting (=rebooting) the target RT controller is quite time consuming, I'd like to know **if there's another solution to undeploy or disconnect an old project from/reset the target RT controller?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Compare Project & System` dialog can be used to resolve conflicts and to redeploy a modified project on the target system. This dialog can be accessed through Project Explorer from the `Utilites` submenu of the target devices context menu.

[image: Compare Project & System dialog]

Answer (score 0):

After you have reopened the LabVIEW project. Right click on the target and go to connect. It will tell you that the target is in use. Do it again and it will connect.